# Expectation of lost ball number

Tags: probability, expected-value

I have expectation problem that sounds like this:

> In the box we have **5 balls** numbered **U={2,2,2,3,3}**. We lost one
>   ball and we don't know which one. Then one ball was taken out from the
>   box which number is **X**. Calculate **E[X]**

I've tried to solve it like this:

> H2 - '2' ball has been lost; H3 - '3' ball has been lost.
>
> Then I calculated probabilities:
>
> A - '2' ball was taken B - '3' ball was taken.
>
> P(A) = P(H2)*P(A|H2)+P(H3)*P(A|H3)= 15/20
>
> P(B) = P(H2)*P(B|H2)+P(H3)*P(B|H3)= 10/20
>
> And then E[X]=(2*15/20)+(3*10/20)=60/20

However, I found somewhere that the answer might be 61/20. But I'm not sure.

So I would really like to know if my solve is correct.
Thank you!

Comment: Both $\frac{60}{20}=3$ and $\frac{61}{20}=3.05$ are wrong, as the expected value is less than $3$: you cannot get more than $3$ and you might get a $2$ with positive probability.  You should have $P(A)+P(B)=\frac{12}{20}+\frac{8}{20}=1$ but for some reason you do not

Comment: That's interesting. Basically my first idea of calculating both probabilities was something like this: P(A) = (3/5*3/4)+(2/5*2/4) = 12/20 and P(B) = (3/5*2/4)+(2/5*1/4) = 8/20

Comment: Try $P(A)=\frac35 \times \frac24 + \frac25 \times \frac34$

Comment: Looks like I've got something, but it's nothing similar to the answer I have. Probably the answer I've got was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the correct formula,  but miscalculated.

$P(A)=P(A\mid H_2)~P(H_2)+P(A\mid H_3)~P(H_3)\\\qquad= \tfrac 24\cdot\tfrac 35+\tfrac 34\cdot\tfrac 25\\\qquad =\tfrac 35$

Similarly $P(B)=\tfrac 25$

Reevaluate your expectation with these values.

---

Also, think about what this is telling you about the effect of the missing ball on the expectation for the second ball.

Comment: So basically there's is no change of probabilities even if the ball is taken from one box to another?

Comment: Indeed.  Look at it this way: I take the five balls, cover each of them with a cup and shuffle them around like a shell game, then randomly label one cup "missing" and another $X$. What is the probability that a $2$ is under cup $X$?

Answer (score 1):

The "lost ball" is a distractor, completely irrelevant.  If two balls are drawn from the box, you need to find the expected value of the second...

...and then "second" is just a distractor too.  You need to find the expected value if one ball is drawn from the box.  Can you do this?